# Burninate the [section] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [section](/questions/tagged/section) tag has no clear use and adds nothing to the existing questions.

Can this be burninated? It has too many questions to untag manually.

**EDIT:** Is there a specific reason why this still hasn't been burninated (probably just over looked)? I will offer a bounty if needed :p

Comment: I think the HTML5 `<section>` tag and when to use it might be reasonable. I agree that it's overly broad though or too localized.